# App not working in higher than Android API Level 10

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I have created an Android app with API level 8 using sencha-touch/phonegap. I have tested this app in android device with 2.3.3 version and also in android emulator API level 13 and 17. But in API level 13 and 17, app is launched but probably network request is not happening. I am guessing this because no carousel image is displayed. Any idea why this app is not working in API level 13 and 17 and why only in API level 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out myself after months(!!!) of failed attempts. Problem was in config.xml file in this line

```
<access origin="localhost" />
```

and it is ok now after I have changed it to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

This single line of code just make me wasted my months of attempts :-(
Hope this helps if anyone have this kind problem